# Visual studio code only runs first test function in unittest module

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-unittest

When I run a python unittest module in the Test window on Visual Studio Code, only the first test function in the test class runs. Is this a bug in VS Code or did I configure this wrong? How can I get all the tests in a module to run when I click the run button?

I've made sure that my tests are discovered properly. I can also successfully run each test individually and by clicking "run all tests". The problem only occurs when I click the "run" button at the module level in the test window:

[image: test window]

Folder structure is

- unittestproblem

  - mycode.py
  - tests

    - test_mycode.py

Here's my code:

```py
import unittest

from mycode import MyClass

class TestMycode(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_foo(self):
        bar = MyClass().foo(1)
        self.assertEqual(bar, 2)

    def test_fooAgain(self):
        bar = MyClass().foo(2)
        self.assertEqual(bar, 3)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

```py
class MyClass():
    def foo(self,x):
        return x + 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An issue is created about that: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/4567.

I guess you should report this quite simple example there as it's easily reproducible.

Btw, I've been able to reproduce the error on Ubuntu 18.04.3.